# Codeanywhere Browse(inactive)

Tags: dropbox, codeanywhere

I just downloaded Codeanywhere app for my Ipad. I want it to connect to my projects via Dropbox and that is not the problem. The problem is whenever i need to see the result of my code aka html/php/css/js then I am told I need to press the browser button.

Only thing is I can't press the Browser button. It says (Inactive) 
[image]

Anyone knows whats up and what one should do?

I have been trying for some time to find an app that would suit my needs and this one will if I can get the browse button to work.

thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what is up. Codeanywhere's app simply does not support the browse though it appears so. However they are working on it at the moment and expect to release a beta during next month.